# W/libdbus ( 985): Failed to start message bus: Failed to open "/etc/dbus.conf": Permission denied

Tags: d-bus

In the log of one of my embedded devices, the following message appears:

```
W/libdbus (  985): Failed to start message bus: Failed to open "/etc/dbus.conf": Permission denied
```

Device is: IconBit XDS73D mk2

Linux version 2.6.34-VENUS (zpl1025@ubuntu20) (gcc version 4.3.6 20110218 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #68 PREEMPT Mon Dec 9 17:59:31 CST 2013

What does this message mean?

Answer (score 1):

The DBus is an IPC-Bus, a Bus for inter-process-communication. There are two standard message bus instances, the system- and the a session- (user) bus.  The DBus Daemon loads a config file at the start named /etc/system.conf or /etc/session.conf. Maybe its named otherwise as dbus.conf on your system.

I would say that the process on your system wants to start a sessionbus but has no permission to open said configfile. Check if the file is readable or try updating your libdbus package. libdbus is the low-level library for the DBus.

I am fairly new to the topic too, hope I could help.

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/